# How to decide on travel to possible Zika zone while pregnant

Tags: health, argentina, pregnancy, zika

I have x-posted on the health stack site.

Anyone with first hand knowledge about traveling to Argentina while 4 months pregnant? The [CDC](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/notices/alert/zika-virus-argentina) states that Argentina is a Level 2 Alert country (Practice Enhanced Precautions) and pregnant women should not go there. However I wonder if this is an overly cautious approach.

The places of interest would be urban settings in Buenos Aires (city), Mar del Plata (seaside), Bariloche (Patagonia), and possibly Corrientes/Resistencia (northeast).

Comment: Not an expert but if a child is at risk, I wouldn't go there. Sure, someone can tell you that the chance is lower or higher but it is still there.

Comment: @Itai but by that reasoning isn't a child at risk on the way to school since a car/bus accident could happen?

Comment: Anything can happen anywhere they say, but it's about how much you can reduce the risk. We don't let small kids cross the street alone or talk to strangers for that reason. It's not have something bad will happen, it's to avoid the rare time that it could. The consequences of Zika are to serious to leave to chance IMO. I do have 3 kids and, yes, we have to be careful with them every day. Repellent is rarely 100% effective - not eve close - which makes avoiding the risk very difficult.

Answer (score 6):

The CDC and WHO are always (understandably) over-cautious, they don't want to risk an outbreak or be accused of not warning people.

Indeed, as recently as [last year there was a Zika case in Buenos Aires](http://www.buenosairesherald.com/article/208095/new-case-of-zika-in-argentina-confirmed). [While previously it was contained to the Tucumán province](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/notices/alert/zika-virus-argentina), it doesn't mean it couldn't spread or be transmitted in an airport, for example.

While any first hand info is going to be merely anecdotal, if you're pregnant, you should speak to your clinician/doctor about preventative methods, as they'll have the latest information, or access to it at least, as this is a reasonably quickly changing situation.  They may advise against it, or provide you with some preventative measures.

Remember, not getting medical advice, or going against government/medical advice can cause some insurance policies to decline any claims, so best to check with your travel insurance as well as to what they recommend, as opposed to a random first hand knowledge on the internet.

Hope that helps a little.